# Is the adrenalline in steak, mutton or other animal meat, poisonous or harmful to us?

Tags: meat

I know there's this question which is [almost a duplicate](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19994/does-the-means-of-slaughter-affect-meat-quality), but this question is about whether the meat is poisonous.

A person who worked in the fisheries department said he studied this. That fishes subjected to trauma had poor quality meat. He also cited this as the reason that Muslims drain the blood from animals before eating them, so as to remove the blood which may contain adrenaline which is released because the animal is afraid of being killed ([probably untrue](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18628/is-halal-meat-healthier-to-consume)). This person said that the adrenaline is poisonous to us if we eat such meat.

Studies of lesser lactic acid in the meat and dryness of the meat (the indicators of meat quality which they mention) is different from what this person told me, about meat being poisonous. I couldn't find any evidence of this. Could it just be a myth propagated by vegans?

Comment: Considering that humans have been eating meat since long before they even WERE humans, I doubt the poisonous claim could hold up.  There are plenty of links to articles showing that it has no effect when administered orally, presumably in far higher doses than you'd get by eating a bit of meat.  E.g. http://www.google.com/url?url=http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/726456_2&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiplsHu_bDRAhVD2WMKHTLvA-wQFggbMAI&sig2=mprkWQ8lMjnp4YBKicHY_w&usg=AFQjCNHC4lqIaOm8jpyT_VMqMV2MRbLIzQ

Comment: While that's sound logic, we do consume poisons everyday and it doesn't kill us immediately but the toxins accumulate and is harmful. I wonder if that's what the person meant. In any case, please post as an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: But remember that it's the dose that makes the poison.  The world is full of things that are healthy, even necessary, in moderation, but toxic if too much is consumed.  Vitamin A is the classic example: either a deficiency or a surplus can cause serious health problems.